# STM32L4R9 USB not detected

Tags: usb, stm32

I have been working on a project which involved an `STM32L4R9VGT6`.

One part of the project is to use the **USB feature** to send data, and use the **DFU**.
We made a custom board, and we are struggling to make the usb working.

Here are the logs from linux station when you connect the device in usb.

```
[17248.888303] usb 1-4.4: new full-speed USB device number 87 using xhci_hcd
[17248.968500] usb 1-4.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[17249.156369] usb 1-4.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[17249.344318] usb 1-4.4: new full-speed USB device number 88 using xhci_hcd
[17249.428345] usb 1-4.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[17249.616346] usb 1-4.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[17249.724376] usb 1-4-port4: attempt power cycle
[17250.328361] usb 1-4.4: new full-speed USB device number 89 using xhci_hcd
[17250.328498] usb 1-4.4: Device not responding to setup address.
[17250.536388] usb 1-4.4: Device not responding to setup address.
[17250.744336] usb 1-4.4: device not accepting address 89, error -71
[17250.828329] usb 1-4.4: new full-speed USB device number 90 using xhci_hcd
[17250.828453] usb 1-4.4: Device not responding to setup address.
[17251.040409] usb 1-4.4: Device not responding to setup address.
[17251.248337] usb 1-4.4: device not accepting address 90, error -71
[17251.248391] usb 1-4-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
```

I also checked the VBUS voltage, and it's about 3.3V. I also changed the LDO to get a clean 3.3V.
The device is powered through the USB.

We also tied the pin BOOT0 to VCC, to set the STM32 in DFU mode, but nothing happens on the Linux side.
I don't know if it's the right way to do it, and to enter in DFU.
I also checked the clock source, to be sure the 48MHz is well generated. The 48 MHz come from the MSI.
Here a screen from the **clock source**
[image]

I generated the project from STM32CubeMX 6.2.1 with the repo : STM32Cube_FW_L4_V1.17.0

In STM232CUBE, I set the USB_OTG in Device Only mode, I Also enable the interrupt (I see the interrupt happening in the debugger).
Here a screen from the USB part on CubeMx :
[image]

I also disabled the VBUS Sensing, then in the Middleware part, I set the USB_DEVICE to Virtual Comm Port. I did not change the setting on that part.

Did you guys ever faced this kind of problems? Is something is wrong with the generated code ? Or the hardware ?

Thanks for your help.

--
**EDIT**
Unfortunatly I can't share whith you guys the whole schematic. You'll find the USB relative schematic.
Here the MCU: [image]
There, the USB connector part with USB_DM and USB_DP directly connected to PA12 and PA11 : [image]
And here the power supply schematic: [image: enter code here]

Comment: Beware of supply common mode interference on cable from grounded and floating ends. Try a laptop to compare

Comment: Based on what you say so many things can be wrong. Post the schematics. The MCU has built-in DFU bootloader so it should just work even with empty flash - unless there are hardware issues.

Comment: The STM32L4R9VGT6 has a built-in bootloader supporting USB DFU. It is availabe if the bootloader is running, usually by pulling BOOT0 high and resetting the MCU. It is completely independent of what you configure in STM32CubeMX. I think you can also start the bootloader via your own software. Another option is to write your own USB DFU and firmware upgrade software. However, it has nothing to do with a Virtual COM Port. It's a separate USB protocol.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, I tried with a laptot, but the result was the same.

Comment: @Justme I Update my post with some parts of the schematic relative to the usb.

Comment: This could also be a PCB layout issue. Are your USB data lines routed together as a nice differential pair with controlled impedance?

Comment: @brhans the design is not perfect indeed. I made some measurement on D+ and D- and here is one thing, the D+ is tied to +3.3V at the beginning, and the D- is low. But when the pc try to enumerate the device, the D- voltage is about 3.96V. It's really weird

Comment: @A.PLTN 3.96V exceeds allowable value for USB data pin. Are you sure you have no 5V devices pushing up the MCU supply voltage towards 5V? I suspect there are problems either due to manufacturing or in the schematics - too bad you can't show them to fix it.

Comment: "I also checked the VBUS voltage, and it's about 3.3V". That would be wrong. You probably mean VDDUSB.

Comment: The DFU feature you want to use is the one from the built-in bootloader. So forget all you STM32CubeMX settings, forget the external oscillators. They won't be used because the bootloader does not use any of your firmware code. Instead you have to connect the device to your computer, pull BOOT0 high and then reset your device. If it doesn't work, you likely have an electrical issue (even though the schematics looks ok as far as I can see).

Comment: @Justme I updated my post with some parts of the schematics.

Comment: @Codo ok, that's what I thought, but I was not sure on how to enter DFU mode. I'm sure I'm pretty sure I have and hardware issue